# Is it possible to populate without `_id`?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, database

I Set manually an `uid` to each item in my collections...I Want To Know It's Possible that I use `uid` for populate?
I Dont Want Use from '_id' because Have Many collections In My DB And should change many things...somthing like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

    var PersonSchema = new Schema({
        name    : String
      , age     : Number
      , stories : [{ type: String, ref: 'Story' }]
    });

    var StorySchema = new Schema({
        _creator : { type: String, ref: 'Person' }
      , title    : String
      , fans     : [{ type: String, ref: 'Person' }]
    });

    var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);
    var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have a mongodb document without '_id' , if you want to avoid duplication of ids, you can put uid in '_id' before saving the document.
If you keep `uid` seperately, '_id' will get autopopulated as ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear example of how to do it (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

```js
Story.
  find(...).
  populate({
    path: 'fans',
    select: 'name -_id' // <---------------'-_id' exclude _id field.
  }).
  exec();
```